# Python shell is restarted every time when a new module is run

Tags: python, shell, module, restart, python-idle

I use Python 3.1 inside Windows XP and when I try to use more than one module at the same time, the Python shell restarts. What can I do?

This is my module benutzer.py:

```
class Benutzer(object):
    def __init__(self,benutzer):
        self.name =  benutzer
        self.email = None

    def setzeEmail(self, adresse):
        self.email = adresse
```

When I do "Run Module" inside IDLE, the shell says RESTART.

Comment: could you post your code? what does it mean: *try to use more than one module at the same time*. does it restart on import?

Comment: It does restart when I run the module in IDLE. I inserted the code in the question.

Comment: It is the way I did it all the time before.

Comment: I mean, what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to use `Benutzer` in IDLE? You could import `benutzer` if it's located on your `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 4):

IDLE restarts Python to make sure your module gets reloaded properly, because this can sometimes be problematic. This is normal and nothing to be concerned about; it won't happen for other uses of your module.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* something that can be done about it. Rather than running your modules by hitting F5 or clicking run you can load them via `exec(open("other_script.py").read())` as explained here: [How to prevent python IDLE from restarting when running new script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814027/how-to-prevent-python-idle-from-restarting-when-running-new-script/43814798#43814798)